# Sinatra app in a gem

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rubygems

I have a Sinatra application I've created and I'd like to package it as a gem-based binary.

I have my gemspec and gem set up to generate a suitable executable that points to the `my_sinatra_app.rb` (which is executable) but the sinatra server never runs. Any ideas why and how to make it work?

`my_sinatra_app` executable:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end

gem 'my_sinatra_app', version
load Gem.bin_path('my_sinatra_app', 'my_sinatra_app', version)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found out :D

You need to wrap your Sinatra app in a class like so:

```
class MySinatraApp < Sinatra::Application
  # Stuff
end
```

Then in the file that runs the application you can just do `MySinatraApp.run!` Simple :)

Comment: Had exactly the same issue today; this really helped. Thx!